# ConcurrenModificationException with 2 dependent Combos (ZK Framework)

Tags: java, exception, combobox, zk

I have a zul wich has two dependent combos. When an item of the first combo (cb_empresa_detalle) is checked then the second combo (cb_agente_detalle) loads its items.

In my controller I have this code:

```
@EventHandler("cb_empresa_detalle.onSelect")
public void loadAgentes(Event evt) throws WrongValueException,
        InterruptedException {
    if (cb_empresa_detalle.getSelectedItem() != null) {
        idEmpresa = (String) cb_empresa_detalle.getSelectedItem()
                .getValue();
//          cb_agente_detalle.getChildren().clear();
        cb_agente_detalle.getItems().clear();

    (...)
```

This code throws a ConcurrenModificationException in lines (I tried the following two options), when I check in diferent items in first combo:

```
cb_agente_detalle.getChildren().clear(); // is now comented
cb_agente_detalle.getItems().clear();
```

Also, I tried this:

```
while (cb_agente_detalle.getItemCount() > 0) {
cb_agente_detalle.removeChild(cb_agente_detalle.getFirstChild());               
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when you try to delete items from a collection when you're iterating over it using an iterator.

Just make sure it is not the case.